# How to group objects by two fields in an inner class

Tags: java, dictionary, collections, java-8, java-stream

Please help me group objects with inner object by two fields.

I have `List<Man>` and need group them by two built-in address object fields? 
I want to achieve the following structure in the answer 
`Map<String, Map<String, List<Man>>>` where the first string is a city, and second string is street

```
public class Man {
  private String name;
  private Address address;

  public Man(String name, Address address) {
        this.name = name;
        this.address = address;
    }
}

public class Address {
  private String city;
  private String street;

  public Address(String city, String street) {
        this.city = city;
        this.street = street;
    }
}


public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Man> mans = new ArrayList<>();
        mans.add(new Man("Jonh", new Address("NY", "123 street")));
        mans.add(new Man("Alex", new Address("Denver", "6 street")));
        mans.add(new Man("Kate", new Address("NY", "123 street")));
        mans.add(new Man("Mary", new Address("Denver", "12 street")));

  //How can I get the following answer? 
  //Map<String, Map<String, List<Man>>>,  where first string is a city, and second string is street 

  // NY -
  //     |
  //     "123 street" - 
  //                  |
  //                   Man(Jonh...)
  //                   Man(Kate...)
  // Denver -
  //         |
  //         "6 street" -
  //                    |
  //                    Man(Alex...)
  //         |
  //          "12 street" -
  //                       |
  //                       Man(Mary...)

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use nested grouping involving lambdas for such tasks:

```
Map<String, Map<String, List<Man>>> output = mans.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(m ->m.getAddress().getCity(), 
                Collectors.groupingBy(m -> m.getAddress().getStreet())));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use nested `Collectors.groupingBy`:

```
mans.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
        m -> m.getAddress().getCity(), 
        Collectors.groupingBy(m -> m.getAddress().getStreet())))
```

The result is:

```
{
    Denver={
        6 street=[Man@7791a895], 
        12 street=[Man@3a5ed7a6]
}, 
    NY={
        123 street=[Man@6325a3ee, Man@1d16f93d]
    }
}
```

Comment: `toString` for `Man` would help clarify further :)

Answer (score 0):

```
Map<String, Map<String, List<Man>>> output = mans.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(man ->man.getAddress().getCity(), 
            Collectors.groupingBy(m -> m.getAddress().getStreet())));
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. Please edit your answer and add a description of what it does or how it works. Answers without explanations may get deleted because people unfamiliar with the situation may not know what the focus of them is.